# Create a flexbox with text and image next to it

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a flexbox with image and text next to it.
I am not sure why the image is not aligned next to the text? Text kind of stacks below image.

I am trying to make the text and image align in the same row in desktop.
In responsive, I want the image on top and text in the bottom.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  box-shadow: 0.1rem 0.1rem 0.2rem 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  min-height: 375px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(127, 127, 127, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item1">
    <p><img src="/image1.png" style=" float: right; padding-left: 20px;"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item2">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Test1</li>
      <li>Test2</li>
      <li>Test3</li>
      <li>Test4</li>
      <li>Test5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove flex-direction:column; and the float:right; your already used flex wrap so it will wrap on small screen and you dont need the  p tag
ok i used flex-reverse and added flex 1 to the second div

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  box-shadow: 0.1rem 0.1rem 0.2rem 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  min-height: 375px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(127, 127, 127, 1);
}

.flex-item2{flex:1;}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item1">
    <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.6QVXHtV8VbGGXMF5RDWWNwAAAA?pid=ImgDet&w=373&h=560&rs=1" >
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item2">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Test1</li>
      <li>Test2</li>
      <li>Test3</li>
      <li>Test4</li>
      <li>Test5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @newuser if this what you want now you can use justify-content if you want space between the image and the text

Comment: The text should be on left side and image on the right side (desktop mode).

Comment: @newuser a lot of ways to do it  just check this solution and you can remove flex 1 and use justify content instead it for you to choose

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code in this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgnh5opa/12/). It does work responsively when you move the middle slider across. You had some in-line CSS which I removed and it all seemed to work fine. Maybe there is an issue with the width of the containers and this is causing the responsiveness to only work when the view port with is much smaller.
Note: I used a random online image for testing

EDIT: Also note if you would like to change the order of the items just change where they are in HTML as this would be easiest

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  box-shadow: 0.1rem 0.1rem 0.2rem 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  min-height: 375px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(127, 127, 127, 1);
}

img {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item1">
    <p><img src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/short-custom-urls-url-shortener-600w-2233924609.jpg"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-item2">
    <h2>Test</h2>

    <ul>
      <li>Test1</li>

      <li>Test2</li>

      <li>Test3</li>

      <li>Test4</li>

      <li>Test5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```